# Getting data from database with java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on an java project and so far It was going good but now I'm stuck at this problem.
I have working connection database <-> program, I have working login (users and pws are in database) ... App is about parking system... 
In my database I have one table "Upravljanje" (eng. control) where I have 1 ROW and 4 COLUMNS (now, max, cijenaH, oznaka) (eng. cars in parking now, max capacity, price per hour, and ID = 1) all Integers

other stuff is working (they're mostly strings and I think that's my prob)

this is code of problem

```
    public static Upravljanje dohvatiUpravljanje(){
    try{
        Connection conn = kreirajKonekciju();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM upravljanje;";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        Upravljanje upravljanje = new Upravljanje(rs.getInt("max"), rs.getInt("now"), rs.getInt("cijenaH"));
        System.out.println("proba - max - now - cijenah :"+rs.getInt("max"));
        conn.close();
        return upravljanje;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Greska kod dohvacanja podataka o parkingu iz baze: "+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is my red console

```
> Greska kod dohvacanja podataka o parkingu iz baze: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.UpravljanjeFrame.<init>(UpravljanjeFrame.java:104)
    at view.UpravljanjeFrame$1.run(UpravljanjeFrame.java:38)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please can someone help me...

PS THAT RETURN "null" can anyone help me put something smarter?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826247/java-sql-sqlexception-before-start-of-result-set

Comment: I read that post like 10 times and it's not the same, he selects one column and I tried to pull it of in my code but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call .next() from your ResultSet, i.e.:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
if (rs.next())
{
  Upravljanje upravljanje = new Upravljanje(rs.getInt("max"), rs.getInt("now"), rs.getInt("cijenaH"));
  ...
}
```

Or change 'if' to 'while' in case you expect multiple results. rs.getXXX will return the fields for the current row.

Comment: Hvala ivane, you solved my problem :) thank you very much

Comment: @mercyFREAK If he solved your problem, I think he deserved a +1 ?

Comment: I did pressed +1 couple of times. Now again O.o ?

Comment: yeah so everything is ok till now :D