# Can't get image from Mysql blob column

Tags: sql, image, netbeans

I can't get an image to jlabel from my blob column in Mysql database. Here is my code:

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `profilepic` FROM `librarian` WHERE `username` = `Tharindu`");
rs = pst.executeQuery();
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream(1));
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(im);
jlabelpic.setIcon(image);
```

Exception:

```
java.sql.SqlException: Before start of result set
```

How can I add the image?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is not the actual loading of the image but rather retrieving the image from the DB. For pointing to the right row of your result set you first need to call `rs.next();` to move the pointer to the next row as initially the pointer is in row "-1", so just right before your result set.

For further information about it this post might also be helpful: [java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826247/java-sql-sqlexception-before-start-of-result-set)

As code it might look something like this:

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `profilepic` FROM `librarian` WHERE `username` = `Tharindu`");
rs = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream(1));
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(im);
    jlabelpic.setIcon(image);
}
```

I hope this helps you.